# Editing user admin status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently deployed my rails app to Heroku and I want to fix a user to be an admin. My users table has an attribute of admin set to false by default. Is there a way to change the status of this user to true from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can access your Heroku app's console by running:

```
heroku run console --app the_name_of_your_app

user = User.find(...)
user.admin = true
user.save!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access heroku db console using this command.

```
heroku pg:psql
```